# How to connect the library for http requests?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to connect the library to work with queries.

At first I tried to connect [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

My steps:

1. pip install requests
2. in views.py:

```py
    import requests
    ....
    def my_view(request):
        ...
        req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')`
```

And I get an error Internal Server Error

Also I tried to use urllib.request

in views.py:

```py
    import urllib.request
    ....
    def my_view(request):
        ...
        req = urllib.request.Request('https://api.github.com/events')`
```

And I get an error Internal Server Error again

What am I doing wrong?

P.S

views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
import requests
import json
import urllib.request

def check_auth(request):

    #req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')

    #req = urllib.request.Request('https://api.github.com/events')

    return render(request, 'authorization/lc.html')
```

Comment: Post the rest of your view code *and* the error message you see on the console with traceback please.

Comment: Look in your web server error log for the actual error that is being raised.

Comment: @JohnGordon There are no errors in the nginx logs

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, there has to be an error logged somewhere.

Comment: @Selcuk I have no traceback. In browser console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: In a python shell, try to replicate your view code as much as possible, and run it to see if you get the same error.

Comment: Your Python code does not run in `nginx`, you must be using something like `gunicorn`, `uwsgi` etc. Check those logs. Failing that, try using the development server. Also consider enabling `DEBUG` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: @mrmaaak what's your templates directory structure like? can you upgrate it above?

Comment: if your request is as simple as what you showed above, the error seems to be your template structure is not right

Comment: @Selcuk thanks, debug = false showed an error!

Answer (score 0):

Ran the code from my own Django site, it seems to work. So it's probably a problem with the rest of your code.

One way to check is trying requests separately in your console

```
import requests

req=requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
print(req.status_code)
```

If it works in console, it should work in Django view.

And just curious, why do you need to request another site on your own site?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. 
I need to use api, for this and need to make a request

Comment: @mrmaaak what was the issue?